# How to add comma in print statement in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python and learning how to code.
I'm printing last element of my list and sum of the list as-

```
print list[-1],sum
```

But the output is separated by " " and not separated by ",".
Any idea how to separate it by comma?

I'm using Python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

Include it in quotes, like this:

```
print str(list[-1]) + "," + str(sum)
```

Enclosing them in `str()` is unnecessary if `list[-1]` and `sum` are strings.

In general, symbols are interpreted as Python symbols (for example, names like `sum` are interpreted as variable or function names). So whenever you want to print anything as is, you need to enclose it in quotes, to tell Python to ignore its interpretation as a Python symbol. Hence `print "sum"` will print the word sum, rather than the value stored in a variable called `sum`.

Comment: I did that but still there is space before and after comma. It prints like this 23 , 244 but I want it to be 23,244

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: also OP shouldn't use `sum` as a variable name as it's already the sum function.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre also OP shouldn't use `list` as a variable name as it's already the list constructor :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Antimony! It worked

Answer (score 2):

Use the `sep` keyword argument: 
`print(list[-1], sum, sep=',')`

Comment: This only works in Python3. From the OP, `print list[-1],sum` is clearly using Python2.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to compose that together into a string. Depending on what version of Python you're using, you could either do:

```
print "{},{}".format(list[-1], sum)
```

or

```
print "%s,%s" % (list[-1], sum)
```

If you were using Python3.6+, there would be a third option:

```
print(f"{list[-1]},{sum}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.format()` and pass whatever variables you want to get it formatted, for example:

```
x = 1
z = [1, 2, 3]
y = 'hello'
print '{},{},{}'.format(x, z[-1], y)

# prints: 1,3,hello
```